# Another problem with workflow

Tags: workflow

private void createTask1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            createTask1.TaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
            approvalTask_TaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();

```
        **approvalTask_TaskProperties.AssignedTo = workflowProperties.Web.SiteAdministrators[0].LoginName;**


        approvalTask_TaskProperties.DueDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0F);
        approvalTask_TaskProperties.Title = "Approval Required for " + twInfo.Title;
        approvalTask_TaskProperties.Description = "Specify the approval result here .";
        createTask1.TaskProperties = approvalTask_TaskProperties;
    }
```

In the highlighted line I have a problem, It gets
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString

Comment: I fixed this by placing the following code.


  private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TrainingInfo));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(workflowProperties.InitiationData));
            twInfo = (TrainingInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            createTrainingSiteName = twInfo.Code;
            createTrainingSiteUrl = workflowProperties.WebUrl;
        }

however I get another  error, the InitiationData is NULL]

Any idea?

Comment: http://sergeluca.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E8A06D5F2F585013!972.entry - See step 7, I think that might help solve your issue.

Comment: The problem was with the onworkflowactivated, it didnt have the properties well binded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the onworkflowactivated, it didnt have the properties well binded, after I binded them, I got the initiationData not null